# sql: no result when SELECT and wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day, 
I have a problem when executing the following code is shows "Commands Completed successfully" but no result from my SELECT *PROBLEM 1*, and also when executed seperayly it works but the result change the whole time*PROBLEM 2* e.g result1: 10:41 executed again 20:82. I just need it to be 10:41 (* I am counting how many 'Jobs' are open and closed

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetSocre] 
            @AUD_ID BIGINT,
        @RowCounter BIGINT,
        @DistinctCounter BIGINT,
        @NACounter BIGINT,
        @Total BIGINT,
        @Status NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
    (
        AUD_ID BIGINT,
        RowCounter BIGINT,
        DistinctCounter BIGINT,
        NACounter BIGINT,
        Total BIGINT,
        [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )


    INSERT INTO #tmp1
    EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE]

END
SELECT [Status] AS [Open/Closed], COUNT(*) AS [Status] FROM #tmp1
GROUP BY [Status]
--DROP TABLE #tmp1
```

The other stored proc [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] only counts if all parts of the job are done before it gives it a status of open/closed

Thanx

Comment: please provide sample data = = tqtq

Comment: @StuartLC - that final select **is** part of the stored procedure. The end of a stored procedure is denoted by the end of the batch (i.e. end of the query or a `GO`) and `BEGIN` and `END` are, here, just denoting a block. They're not part of the requirements for a stored procedure definition.

Comment: Ok I've moved my `SELECT [Status] AS [Open/Closed], COUNT(*) AS [Status] FROM #tmp1 GROUP BY [Status]` before the `END` but the result is just showing a message "Command(s) completed successfully." but no Result

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yes, you're right of course. I meant for readability.

Comment: @inzefinite: You will have two tabs. Results & Message... In which tab you are seeing?

Comment: Normal execute: Only in Messages if i hilight `SELECT [Status] AS [Open/Closed], COUNT(*) AS [Status] FROM #tmp1
 GROUP BY [Status]` then it only shows in Results

Comment: BTW if i want to get the percentage of the two columns of the total (open and closed) how whould i do that ive tried something like `SELECT (([Status]*100)/(SELECT MAX([Status])FROM #tmp1))`

Comment: @inzefinite are you executing the script above? Or are you executing the SP? If you execute the script above you will not get any results, because you are altering the SP? If the Select is part of the SP, like one of the answers below, then execute the SP and see what you get. A temp table is active for a specific session. If you execute the SP and then try to select it, it will not work because the temp table is created in a different session. The alternative is    to use a ##tmp1. That is a global temp table until the executing session is dropped

Comment: Just be careful with a ## temp table, because it is a global temp table, it cannot be created in a second session while the first session is still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below...  Drop temp table is not necessary as Proc automatically drops temp table..

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetSocre] 
        @AUD_ID BIGINT,
    @RowCounter BIGINT,
    @DistinctCounter BIGINT,
    @NACounter BIGINT,
    @Total BIGINT,
    @Status NVARCHAR(10)
   AS
    BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
(
    AUD_ID BIGINT,
    RowCounter BIGINT,
    DistinctCounter BIGINT,
    NACounter BIGINT,
    Total BIGINT,
    [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO #tmp1
EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE]

 SELECT [Status] AS [Open/Closed], COUNT(*) AS [Status] FROM #tmp1
GROUP BY [Status]


 END
```

Comment: There's no need to drop a local temp table at the end of a stored procedure that creates said table - they're automatically dropped when the stored proc returns.